# ng Build Prod Error: Says component declared in two modules but its the same module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to run the ng build --prod command, but I keep getting this error:

> Type **SiteSecurity** in "PATH"/siteSecurity.component.ts is part of
>   the declarations of 2 modules: SiteSecurityModule in
>   "PATH"/siteSecurity.module.ts and SiteSecurityModule in
>   "PATH"/siteSecurity.Module.ts!

Note that "PATH" is the same. Its saying that my component is declared by two different modules, but its pointing to the same module.

Code:

siteSecurity.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SiteSecurity } from './siteSecurity.component';
import { AuthGuard } from '../../../../../ReusableServices/AuthGuard';


export const SiteSecurityRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
    {path: 'Datahub/Admin/Auth/SiteSecurity', component: SiteSecurity, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
]);
```

siteSecurity.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SharedModule } from '../../../../../ReusableComponents/SharedModule';
import { SiteSecurity } from './siteSecurity.component';
import { SiteSecurityRouting } from './SiteSecurity.routing';
import { SiteSecurityService } from './siteSecurity.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, SiteSecurityRouting, SharedModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [SiteSecurity],
    providers: [SiteSecurityService]
})
export class SiteSecurityModule {
}
```

SiteSecurityModule is imported into a parent module and is not referenced or imported anywhere else.

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that **SiteSecurity** is in the routing file and the module file, but removing it from either place raises an error. Has anyone seen this before? What am I doing wrong?

@angular/cli version 6.2.4

Comment: I believe paths are case sensitive now... I wonder if the capital M on Module in the two different file names is contributing to your issue. I would search your project for imports to see if you have two, one for siteSecurity.module.ts and one for siteSecurity.Module.ts. possibly confilct between SharedModule and app.module.ts?

Comment: @Marshal you are spot on. In my parent module i specify the import path as 'siteSecurity.Module', but the actual file name is siteSecurity.module. That solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, I have converted comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import paths are case sensitive, the capital M in an import is likely the root issue.